# Strong measure zero sets and selection principles

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology, selection-principles

A set of reals $X$ is *strong measure zero* if for any sequence of positive real numbers $ (  \epsilon_n ) _{n \in \omega }$ there is a sequence of open intervals $ (  a_n ) _{n \in \omega }$ which covers $X$ and such that each $ a_i $ has length less than $ \epsilon _i $.

Does anyone know where can I find a proof that the selection principle $\mathcal S_1(\mathcal O,\mathcal O)$ implies Borel property of strong measure zero? I have seen this in [The Combinatorics of open covers](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.2991/978-94-6239-024-9_18#page-1), but the reference there is to an article which is not in English.
Thank you,

Comment: What is the Borel property of strong measure zero? What  is the reference that is not in English?

Comment: The proof is very short, actually: given the sequence $\epsilon_i$, let $\mathcal{U}_i$ be the cover of $X$ by open intervals of length $\epsilon_i$. Then $\mathcal{S}_1(\mathcal{O},\mathcal{O})$ ensures that there is a cover of $X$ consisting of (at most) one member of each $\mathcal{U}_i$. A more general statement is proved in Theorem 9 in "Finite powers of strong measure zero sets" by M. Scheepers.

Comment: Baillif's answer is correct and complete. Is there a reason why this question appears in MO as unanswered?

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. The answer is very clear. but, I don't know how to mark it as answered. If anyone could please mark it. Thank you!

Comment: @Student: Checkmark the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

To help with @Student's last comment, I post here Baillif's answer.

The proof is very short, actually: given the sequence $\epsilon_i$, let 
$U_i$ be the cover of $X$ by open intervals of length $\epsilon_i$. Then $S_1(O,O)$ ensures that there is a cover of $X$ consisting of (at most) one member of each $U_i$. A more general statement is proved in Theorem 9 in "Finite powers of strong measure zero sets" by M. Scheepers.

–  Mathieu Baillif